# SolidWorks 2014 x64 is giving 0xc000007b error

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, solidworks

I have  autocad 2014 x64 and it does not open after I installed some c++ redistributables. I've already reinstalled both .net and the c++, also reinstalled the directX.

When I run the [dependency walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lseed.png) it gives me the `Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lseed.png]

Comment: run 32Bit depends.exe, because you openede the 32bit solidworks exe

Comment: The first line of your question body mentions AutoCAD, is that simply a typo? Are you certain you have the 64-bit Solidworks rather than 32-bit? Have you modified the executable in any way that could have corrupted it?